# Comments require reader.markSupported() to return true beanio

Tags: java, bean-io

Xml File

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">

        <stream name="stream" format="delimited" ignoreUnidentifiedRecords="true">
            <parser>
                <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
                <property name="comments" value="Response Codes:,|File Trailer|,File Header|"/>
            </parser>

            <group name="HeaderRecord">
                <record>
                .
                .
                .
                </record>
            </group>
            <group name="GroupHeader">
                <record>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                </record>
            </group>
        </stream>
</beanio>
```

File that contains records looks like this

```
1   File Header|
.   HeaderRecord text.....
.   GroupHeader text......
19  Response Codes:
20                 |A - StackOverflow           |                
21                 |B - Facebook                |               
22                 |C - Google                  |                
23  |File Trailer|



Error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comments require reader.markSupported() to return true
    at org.beanio.stream.util.CommentReader.<init>(CommentReader.java:61)
    at org.beanio.stream.delimited.DelimitedReader.<init>(DelimitedReader.java:149)
    at org.beanio.stream.delimited.DelimitedRecordParserFactory.createReader(DelimitedRecordParserFactory.java:56)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.StreamFormatSupport.createRecordReader(StreamFormatSupport.java:61)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.Stream.createBeanReader(Stream.java:88)
```

I want to ignore File Header, Trailer & Response Codes. Response codes starts in next line. Various blogs suggested for comments in property. Can anyone explain why it is not working?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using?

Comment: Fetching file from StreamBeanProvider and reading each line from BeanReader class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `Reader` implementation that you used to read the data from as indicated by the error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comments require
> reader.markSupported() to return true

You need to use a `Reader` that supports buffering, i.e. a `Reader` that implements the `mark()` and `reset()` methods. See [section 4.1.2](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#DelimitedStreamFormat) of the documentation and the description and explanation for the `comments` property name, which states:

> A comma separated list of values for identifying commented lines. If a
> line read from an input stream begins with any of the configured
> values, the line is ignored. A backslash may be used to escape a comma
> and itself. All whitespace is preserved.
>
> Enabling comments require the input reader passed to StreamFactory to
> support marking. Among others, Java's BufferedReader and StringReader
> support marking.

For comments to work you need to read the data with either a `BufferedReader` or a `StringReader`

```java
InputStream inputStream = ... // obtain some input stream to the source of your data 
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
BeanReader beanReader = factory.createReader("streamName", reader);
```

Comment: When I follow as you said then I get error as

 org.beanio.UnexpectedRecordException: Expected record 'GroupHeader' at line 20
 at org.beanio.internal.parser.UnmarshallingContext.newUnsatisfiedRecordException(UnmarshallingContext.java:372)
 at org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.unmarshal(Group.java:152)
 at org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanReaderImpl.internalRead(BeanReaderImpl.java:106)

Comment: Do you think the error is related to the comments or is it a new error? If it is still related, please update your question with the mapping file and some test data so that we can reproduce the problem. I can't tell what is wrong based on the error message alone.

Comment: Sorry for misguiding you. I have updated my question. Current issue is org.beanio.UnexpectedRecordException: End of stream reached, expected record 'GroupHeader'

Comment: @Tatkal That sounds like a different issue, the original one ("Comments requires reader.markSupported to be true") seems to be resolved by the above comment. Please open a new question for the UnexpectedRecordException.

Comment: @Tatkal It seems the original problem is resolved. Please accept the answer as the correct one if it did indeed answer your original question. For the error message mentioned above please ask a new question. The updated `mapping.xml` file is also not enough information to reproduce the problem. Show the Java classes with their properties/fields, sample data to test with, the full mapping.xml file. The more information and code you provide, the easier it is to reproduce the problem and help you.